# Laravel 5 Database TIME Field Error

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, time

I`m new to the laravel 5.4.so that when i implement a CRUD application so that in one feild i have to enter time period.so i add time period as 13.00-14.00 then after i save it gives this error.

[image]

Here is my Migration

```
*/
public function up()
{
     Schema::create('trainingprogramedetails', function (Blueprint $table) {

         $table->increments('id');
         $table->date('date_of_programe');
            $table->time('time');
            $table->string('venue');
            $table->string('training_programe_id');
            $table->string('presenter_name');
            $table->string('division');
            $table->date('date');
         $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are trying to insert 13.00-14.00 in you column it return invalid datetime because you enter data is not in time format if you using laravel then you also insert like this

```
$ckeck = DB::table('tablename')->insertGetId(array(
                    'tittle'        => $data['title'],
                    'discription'   => $data['description'],
                    'flag'          => '0',
                    'created_at'    => Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at'    => Carbon::now()
                    ));
```

and if you want to enter time like 13.00-14.00 then you have change you column type to varchar or text

for further query you can also flow this link
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#inserts

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you are trying to insert `13.00-14.00` in a column whose datatype is `time` as defined here:

```
$table->time('time');
```

To solve it, either change the `datatype` of column from `time` to `string` or pass the proper time value in it.